# What are alternatives to Asterisq's Constellation Framework for actionscript?

Tags: python, flash, actionscript, html, visualization

i would like to present data in something like Constellation Framework... but without flash

what other options are out there? python, html5, javascript would be great, but i have no preference other than no flash (i don't own CS)

EDIT: i have found a handful of html5 examples without much source code and infoVis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know of two good options which will work in Javascript:

1. [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/)
2. [The JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/)

In Java, I would recommend [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/).  I don't know off hand of Python Network libraries, but I'm sure there are some.